# Redirecting to some error Page on some other domain in CQ5

Tags: redirect, aem

I want to understand how do i redirect the page from one domain to another domain. For example i want to make the site down (www.abc.com) and redirect to some error page of different domain (www.123.com/errorpage). Is there any way we can do this in etc folder instead of virtualhost file. Both the domain are in the same server. Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about Sling Mappings at https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/mappings-for-resource-resolution.html.

Create the path `/etc/map/http` all type `sling:Folder`. Then add the following two nodes:

```
abc
    jcr:resourceType="sling:Mapping"
    sling:match="abc.com(/.*)"
    sling:redirect="http://www.123.com/errorpage.html"

abc80
    jcr:resourceType="sling:Mapping"
    sling:match="abc.com.80(/.*)"
    sling:redirect="http://www.123.com/errorpage.html"
```

You can work from here to make any additions or alterations based on your ports and how you handle "www" redirects.

Sling mappings support regular expression groups. If `sling:match` was set to `abc.com.80` the resulting redirect would end up at `http://www.123.com/errorpage.html/content/sitename/page.html` which is obviously incorrect. We can update the `sling:redirect` property to `http://www.123.com/errorpage.html?from=$1` in order to utilize the captured group. In this example, however, I'm simply discarding the captured group. Either way, the trick to getting to the desired redirection is to set the capture group.

You can test on your local author instance with the following settings:

```
localhost4502
    jcr:resourceType="sling:Mapping"
    sling:match="localhost.4502(/.*)"
    sling:redirect="http://www.google.com/error.html"
```

`sling:redirect` defaults as a temporary 302 redirect. If you wanted, you could set `sling:status` to 300, 301, 303 or 307. If you didn't need to change the address bar, you could use `sling:internalRedirect` which would behave more like an Apache internal rewrite as opposed to an external redirect. See the docs for more options.